# Не работает команда java в консоли

Tags: java

лог

```
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

Java скачал JDK скачал, JRE скачал все последней версии для виндовс.

Comment: Предоставьте код чтоб указать на проблемы. И команду которую вы вызываете

Comment: Проверьте перемнную среды `JAVA_HOME`, какой путь там указан?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2 путь

Comment: Вызываю команду java -versions